# Preventing unnecessary rendering in Meteor if a document referenced by two templates in Meteor is updated

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor project where two different templates depend on data from the same document:

```
{ "title": "My Project", "data": "My project data" }
```

One template renders the "title", and another renders the "data".

If a user changes the "data" field in the document, I do not want the template that uses the "title" field to re-render. I only want the template that uses "data" to re-render.

For example, the title may be in a page header which does not need to be re-rendered if the project's data changes.

How can this be achieved?

My Meteor templates:

```
<head>
  <title>experiment</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{>hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
    <div>
        My projects.
    </div>

    {{#each projects}}
    <div>
        {{>projectTitle}}
        {{>projectData}}
    </div>
    {{/each}}

</template>

<template name="projectTitle">
    <div>
        Project title: {{title}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="projectData">
    <div>
        Project data: {{data}} 
    </div>
</template>
```

My Meteor Javascript:

```
Experiments = new Meteor.Collection("experiments");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.projects = function() {
    return Experiments.find();
  }

  Template.projectTitle.title = function() {
    return Experiments.find().fetch()[0].title;
  }

  Template.projectData.data = function() {
    return Experiments.find().fetch()[0].data;
  }

  Template.projectTitle.rendered = function() {
    console.log('Rendered projectTitle');
  }

  Template.projectData.rendered = function() {
    console.log('Rendered projectData');
  }
}
```

This code will currently output "Rendered projectTitle" and "Rendered projectData" whenever either of the fields in the Project document change, which shows that both templates are being re-rendered.

**Edit** I don't know if there is a 'correct' way to do this, but one could publish two subscriptions, which return separate parts of the document. This seems counter to the philosophy of Meteor, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your templates read from a `Session` variable, and then set the Session variable appropriately using `Meteor.autorun`.

Then when your object changes, `Meteor.autorun` will execute again, but the Session won't change if the field didn't change.